# Using awk to modify a file deletes its contents

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
A_,4.3.01.98
B_,4.3.01.98
C_,4.3.01.98
C_,4.3.01.98
E_,4.3.01.98
F_,4.3.01.98
G_,4.3.01.98
H_,4.3.01.98
```

I use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$4 = $4 + 1; print}' file_name` in order to increment the last field and it works fine, but for some reason, when adding `> file_name` [`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$4 = $4 + 1; print}' file_name > file_name`] it deletes the file contents...

2nd question - How can I ensure the increment won't go over 99 and instead go back to 00 (or any arbitrary N, i.e. *98 -> 99 -> 50 -> 51...*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answer for 1st question:*** you have to add option which is present in `awk` to tell it to save changes into Input_file itself. `gawk` has `-i inplace` option for the same, in case you have it you could use it then. In case of taking backup you could try `gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak` too.

***Answer for 2nd question:*** I added into the to solution: Since my `awk` is old version `awk` so I made another way to save output into Input_file itself. I am taking output into a output file named `temp_file` and then putting `&&` condition to make sure previous `awk` command was successfully executed. Then I am renaming the `temp_file` to `Input_file` itself. Also added a condition here if 4th field is less than `99` then simply add 1 to it else set it to `0`.

Following `awk` may help you on both your questions:

```
awk -F"." '{$4=$4<=99?$4++:0;print}' OFS="."  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F"." '{$4=$4<=98?$4+1:0;print}' OFS="."   Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, but when I replaced `++` with `+1` it did

Comment: @CIsForCookies, I added `$4+1` solution too now in post now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's why: when the shell sees `awk '...' file > file`, the **first** thing the shell does is process the redirection to truncate the file and open it for writing. Only then does the shell start up awk. But by then the file is empty.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

> *Before a command is executed*, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell. (emphasis mine)

---

The moreutils linux package has a [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sponge.1.html) command you can use for this purpose:

```
awk '...' file | sponge file
```